# UITableView, another cell in invisible area has a checkmark while one in visible area is touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my code, which shows a problem for 14 rows of a table view. For one screen, 6 cells are visible.

When I tapped the 2nd cell, the 10 cell also has a checkmark, tap 3rd then 11th checkmarked, 1st then 9th checkmarked, tap 1st, then 8th also checkmarked...but the grey highlight does not behave like this, only one cell can be highlighted.

If I tap a cell after one is tapped on the the same screen, the one just checkmarked will be cleared for checkmark, which makes sense. However,  if after I tapped one cell and then scroll the tableview lower, I can tap a cell and it shows checkmark as well, i.e. the one just checked on top screen still has a checkmark. So if I scroll up and down, and tap one cell each time after I scroll to the other side, I can put a checkmark for every cell, all checkmarks are shown.

It is really weird, and I have tried a lot of ways to solve it, but seems I have some basic understanding of `UITableView` missing, can anyone figure it out, please? Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *ID= @"UITableViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ID];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"earth.png"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not storing the existence/absence of your checkmark in any sort of persisted data source and showing/hiding it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Because of this, your table is reusing your cells, and it just throws it up as it found it. So if it reuses a cell that had your checkmark accessory enabled, it shows it as enabled (because you didn't specifically disable it in `cellForRow`)

I would keep an `NSMutableArray` of selected `indexPath` objects. Add the `indexPath` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and remove it in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check if the current `indexPath` exists in the array and enable the checkmark if so, disable if not.

Comment: I am just wondering, is this kind of knowledge written in Apple's documentation? I've checked the reference doc of UITableView delegate methods, it does not write much about how to set accessory type. I am curious have you ever made mistakes like me, and then you figured it out?

Comment: Mostly experience. But it's not just accessory types. Anything that you don't explicitly set in `cellForRow` will be maintained in a reused cell. So if you change the background color on a cell somewhere, but don't check/set that same background color when the cells are displayed, it will likely be reused incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

[Stonz2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018795/3137158) is right.
For example, you should create an object for table view data source and it should has a property to show is it checkmarked.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    Item *item = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (item.checkmarked) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    Item *tappedItem = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.checkmarked = !tappedItem.checkmarked;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


}
```